# Windows 8 asp pages is getting different date format

Tags: asp.net, windows-8, asp-classic

recently I updated my OS to windows 8 when installing Region and location mentioned India after my application tested,
 I found some Date time issue in asp.net pages so I changed region and location to United states

so that issue fixed after that asp pages also giving me the same problem I changed in registry culture info en-IN to en-US and sDate format to mm/dd/yyyy but in asp page

when I am converting date time to string by using Cdate(DATE) it is giving me dd-mm-yyyy. How can I get mm/dd/yyyy format?

so please help me to solve this

Comment: not sure why the down-vote? Seems like a complete-enough question to me.

Comment: I don't know who did this down vote can you please explain me whats the wrong with this question

Comment: Coming to this much later, but my guess is that it had to do with your tags. ASP.Net and asp-classic are very different animals. Which one did you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add `<globalization />` into your web config. This will ensure the site ignores whatever settings are on the server (your PC in this case..)

Add the following to your web.config

```
      <system.web>
          <globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-US" />
      </system.web>
```

Once this is done you will be able to put your own PC's settings back to Indian language if you like.

Alternatively, you can add a format to the `ToString` of your `DateTime`.

I.E

```
     myDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: I tried this thing but still it is not working and I changed IIS globalization settings also still its not working

Comment: you must have something else overriding the web.config then. Do you have a different culture set on pages/master page? This code 100% sets the culture format to mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: I changed in every web.config file globalization property if I am getting only date value it is giving me correct in asp.net and If I use Convert.todatetime and toString() in asp.net is working but in asp if get only datetime as a object it is givvi me correct datetime format if I convert that date object to string it is giving me en-IN format

Comment: Hard to say, sounds like you have some configuration issues more than coding. I added something to my answer that will allow you to set the specific format of the `DateTime.ToString()` method